# Time series plot of assets - change transparency based on another matrix

Tags: python, pandas

I have a matrix of prices for five assets in my pandas dataframe `pri_fin_mat` and another matrix containing zeroes and ones for the very same five assets in my pandas dataframe `b_mat`. The two dataframes have the same index and shapes. I want to plot `pri_fin_mat` but make the line of a certain column *more transparent* whenever there is a zero on that particular row in the `b_mat`.

## MCVE

The code below produces a time series plot of an stock index and a bond index. I want to make it so that during 2015 and 2018 the equity line is of a more transparent color, and during 2016 the bond index is of a more transparent color.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

start = '2015-01-01'
end = '2018-01-01'
dtindex = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='D')

stocks = web.DataReader('^SPX', 'stooq', start, end)
bonds = web.DataReader('BND.US', 'stooq', start, end)
prices = pd.concat([stocks.Close, bonds.Close], axis=1)

prices.plot()
```

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @sophros I did that now